# Are you allowed to redefine whole class in ruby without loading the original one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I have a module from a gem I have not control over. The gem's version of module plays bad with new rails active support library. (Details are: the gem's module code extends the Active Support's callbacks module and it causes an exception)

I want to override the module. The classic monkey patching assumes that we load the original gem code first and then we override some methods in our host application and the problem here that in my case an attempt to load the original gem causes the error.

Thank you, guys!

**Update**
So on the module's load:

```rb
module GemName
  module ProblematicModule
    extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  end
end
```

exception arises that the `class_attribute` method is not found on module. I think it is due to the AS callback code (v5.2):

```rb
  module Callbacks
    extend Concern

    included do
      extend ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker
      class_attribute :__callbacks, instance_writer: false, default: {}
    end
```

Comment: _"are you allowed to [...]"_ – you can do whatever you want :-) Joking apart, it would help to see _how_ the gem's code causes that error. There's probably a way to prevent it from extending Active Support (if that is what you want), but without any code we can hardly provide a solution.

Comment: @Stefan added some details. thaank you!

Comment: The [`class_attribute`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb#L85) method is only added to `Class`, not `Module`. Your gem was probably written for an older Rails version that didn't have this method. It's used to define a `__callbacks` method on the class which then holds the defined 
callbacks in a hash. You could try to add the method to the module manually (probably as a class method), however I'm not sure if that results in working callbacks. In the long run, it would probably be better to replace the outdated gem.

Comment: @Stefan yup. thanks. Seems like decent workaround. Try to just reopen the Module class and copy the method source code

Comment: Since callbacks need a class, I assume that "ProblematicModule" is included into other classes which then define their callbacks. If so, the actual fix would be to either move the `extend ActiveModel::Callbacks` call right into those classes or to invoke the call within an `included` callback from the module so it gets evaluated in the context of the including class. This is probably a little too much for a patch – you could maybe fork the gem and update it yourself.

Comment: @Stefan one gotcha to look out for with `Module#included` is that its only fired when you initially include the module and not for classes that inherit from the class that includes the module. The way to work around this is to move the "setup" into a class method and call that method from both the included and [inherited hooks](https://blog.appsignal.com/2019/09/03/inherited-hook-method-and-parenting.html).

Comment: *"you could maybe fork the gem and update it yourself"* -- this is what I was going to say. At this point it's probably better to just make your own version of the gem than attempt to "hack" it with metaprogramming.